# Focal point: How can I dynamically write data in this code case?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically write data(in JavaScript)inside my HTML table, but haven't been able to thrive so far. I am relatively new to frontend, especially JS. I would highly appreciate any suggestion on how to get this to function properly. I have tried `.innerHTML` method, `.innerText` etc, but no good to show for it. Here's my `index.html` and `app.js` files, so anybody can look into it. Thank you soo much in advance!

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Trainee React Developer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <h1>Star Wars API Fetch</h1>
  </header>

  <main class="main-content">
    <h3>Here's Star Wars fetched data: </h3>
    <div id="sw-data">
      <table id="table">
        <thead id="t-header">
          <tr id="row-headings">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Eye Color</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
            <th>Number of vehicles</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-content">
            <tr>
               <td id="name-data"></td>
               <td id="eye-color-data"></td>
               <td id="height-data"></td>
               <td id="birth-year-data"></td>
               <td id="vechicles-data"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS Code:

```
   const urlFetch = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'; /*fetch  request adress*/
                    
let charNameCell = document.getElementById('name-data');
let charEyeColorCell = document.getElementById('eye-color-data');
let charHeightCell = document.getElementById('height-data');
let charBirthYearCell = document.getElementById('birth-year-data');
let charVehiclesCell = document.getElementById('vehicles-data');



const fetchAPI = async () => {//Fetching data function
    try {
        const response = await fetch(urlFetch);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.results); 
       
        data.results.forEach(result => {
            console.log(result); 
            charNameCell.innerHTML = result.name;
            charEyeColorCell.innerHTML = result.eye_color;
            charHeightCell.innerHTML = result.height;
            charBirthYearCell.innerHTML = result.birth_year;
            charVehiclesCell.innerHTML = result.vehicles.length;
          
        });  
    } 
    catch {   
       console.log('Oooops, something is wrong!');
    } 
     finally {
        console.log("Fetch session completed!");
    }
}

fetchAPI();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the most part your code is very well written, but since you have only the one row within the table, it is only populating the data in this row. To get the table dynamically populating, I would suggest removing the existing row from the table and the JS variables that relate to the table cells. Then by referencing the table body, a row can be populated for each result, as follows:

```js
const urlFetch = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'; /*fetch  request adress*/
                    
let tableBody = document.getElementById('table-content');

const fetchAPI = async () => {//Fetching data function
  try {
      const response = await fetch(urlFetch);
      const data = await response.json();

      data.results.forEach(result => {
          const row = tableBody.insertRow(-1),
            nameCell = row.insertCell(-1),
            eyeColorCell = row.insertCell(-1),
            heightCell = row.insertCell(-1),
            birthYearCell = row.insertCell(-1),
            vehiclesCell = row.insertCell(-1);
            
          nameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.name));
          eyeColorCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.eye_color));
          heightCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.height));
          birthYearCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.birth_year));
          vehiclesCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.vehicles.length));
          
          result.vehicles.length === 0 && vehiclesCell.classList.add('highlight');
      });  
  } 
  catch {   
     console.log('Oooops, something is wrong!');
  } 
   finally {
      console.log("Fetch session completed!");
  }
}

fetchAPI();
```

```css
.highlight {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-content">
    <h3>Here's Star Wars fetched data: </h3>
    <div id="sw-data">
      <table id="table">
        <thead id="t-header">
          <tr id="row-headings">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Eye Color</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Birth Year</th>
            <th>Number of vehicles</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-content">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </main>
```

**Edit** - Following the comment, I have added the following line in to highlight a cell where the character has no vehicle. Obviously you could extend this as required. `result.vehicles.length === 0 && vehiclesCell.classList.add('highlight');`

Comment: Thank you soo much my friend.Tried out what you suggested, and everything fits in just perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: Could i please ask you for one more little favor?How can i dinamically paint background into certain color;for example: if I wanted to highlight characters from the API that got no vehicles, or the shortest character etc?